# How to access graphql docs (/graphiql) from AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, graphiql

I am using Netflix Dgs Graphql in my application.

I have deployed my application in AWS exposing it using Application Load Balancer. I have configured port 443 and 80 in ingress rules and port 8080(Application port) in outgress rules.

When I want to access the graphql User Interface (/graphiql), I am getting 404 error. But in local I can able to access the /graphiql with this localhost: http://localhost:8081/demo-graphql-app/graphiql

And all other graphql apis I can able to access via load balancer.

Should I need to expose any other port apart from 443 and 80 for graphiql to access? Please help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So on local, your main application is at `http://localhost:8080` and the graphiql interface is at `http://localhost:8081`? In other words, the graphiql interface is on a separate port from the rest of the application?

Comment: No, in local I am pointing my application to 8081. In aws I am pointing to 8080

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue.

In my application I have enabled the graphiql property.

I am using spring boot application, so in my properties file I have added the following

```
dgs:
  graphql:
    graphiql:
      enabled: true
```